# Exception encountered during context initialization - Incompatible library?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I follow [this tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/) but after all I get an error, and I don't understand why!!!

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringExample</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>SpringExample</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

this is my controller

```
package org.dstech.examplespring.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.dstech.examplespring.model.Employee;
import org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * @author franksisca
 *c
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    /*
     * This method will list all existing employees.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap model) {

        List<Employee> employees = service.findAllEmployees();
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        return "allemployees";
    }

    /*
     * This method will provide the medium to add a new employee.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newEmployee(ModelMap model) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        return "registration";
    }

    /*
     * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
     * saving employee in database. It also validates the user input
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployee(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        /*
         * Preferred way to achieve uniqueness of field [ssn] should be implementing custom @Unique annotation 
         * and applying it on field [ssn] of Model class [Employee].
         * 
         * Below mentioned peace of code [if block] is to demonstrate that you can fill custom errors outside the validation
         * framework as well while still using internationalized messages.
         * 
         */
        if(!service.isEmployeeSsnUnique(employee.getId(), employee.getSsn())){
            FieldError ssnError =new FieldError("employee","ssn",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssn", new String[]{employee.getSsn()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssnError);
            return "registration";
        }

        service.saveEmployee(employee);

        model.addAttribute("success", "Employee " + employee.getName() + " registered successfully");
        return "success";
    }


    /*
     * This method will provide the medium to update an existing employee.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-{ssn}-employee" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable String ssn, ModelMap model) {
        Employee employee = service.findEmployeeBySsn(ssn);
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        return "registration";
    }

    /*
     * This method will be called on form submission, handling POST request for
     * updating employee in database. It also validates the user input
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/edit-{ssn}-employee" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEmployee(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model, @PathVariable String ssn) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        if(!service.isEmployeeSsnUnique(employee.getId(), employee.getSsn())){
            FieldError ssnError =new FieldError("employee","ssn",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssn", new String[]{employee.getSsn()}, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(ssnError);
            return "registration";
        }

        service.updateEmployee(employee);

        model.addAttribute("success", "Employee " + employee.getName()  + " updated successfully");
        return "success";
    }


    /*
     * This method will delete an employee by it's SSN value.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/delete-{ssn}-employee" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable String ssn) {
        service.deleteEmployeeBySsn(ssn);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

}
```

and this is application initializer

```
package org.dstech.examplespring.configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

/**
 * @author franksisca
 *
 */
public class HelloWorldInit  implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)
     */
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(HelloWorldConfig.class);
        context.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = 
                servletContext.addServlet
                ("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

and last, but not least, my console error when i start tomcat

```
AVVERTENZA: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'appController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.dstech.exam
plespring.service.EmployeeService org.dstech.examplespring.controller.AppController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
 qualifying bean of type [org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency
. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
mag 18, 2016 6:09:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springfr
amework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService org.dstech.examplespring.controller.AppController.service; n
ested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService] found for dependen
cy: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=tr
ue)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService org.dstech.examplespring.controller.A
ppController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeServ
ice] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotatio
n.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expe
cted at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 28 more
```

Can anyone help me? I think it's a problem with jade.time library, but i don't know how to solve. If I use java.util.Date i get the same error.

---

EDIT

Sorry, i forget my service

```
public interface EmployeeService {

    Employee findById(int id);

    void saveEmployee(Employee employee);

    void updateEmployee(Employee employee);

    void deleteEmployeeBySsn(String ssn);

    List<Employee> findAllEmployees(); 

    Employee findEmployeeBySsn(String ssn);

    boolean isEmployeeSsnUnique(Integer id, String ssn);

}
```

and this is my implementation

```
@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao dao;

    public Employee findById(int id) {
        return dao.findById(id);
    }

    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        dao.saveEmployee(employee);
    }

    /*
     * Since the method is running with Transaction, No need to call hibernate update explicitly.
     * Just fetch the entity from db and update it with proper values within transaction.
     * It will be updated in db once transaction ends. 
     */
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Employee entity = dao.findById(employee.getId());
        if(entity!=null){
            entity.setName(employee.getName());
            entity.setJoiningDate(employee.getJoiningDate());
            entity.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
            entity.setSsn(employee.getSsn());
        }
    }

    public void deleteEmployeeBySsn(String ssn) {
        dao.deleteEmployee(ssn);
    }

    public List<Employee> findAllEmployees() {
        return dao.findAllEmployees();
    }

    public Employee findEmployeeBySsn(String ssn) {
        return dao.findEmployeeBySsn(ssn);
    }

    public boolean isEmployeeSsnUnique(Integer id, String ssn) {
        Employee employee = findEmployeeBySsn(ssn);
        return ( employee == null || ((id != null) && (employee.getId() == id)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Stack trace,its clearly stated that it is not able to find EmployeeService.

```
 No qualifying bean of type [org.dstech.examplespring.service.EmployeeService]
```

You are trying to autowire `EmployeeService` in the controller where it is failing

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService service;
```

Just check if you have defined this `EmployeeService` bean in the applicationContext or you have annotated it with `@Service`

Comment: Please share your EmployerService Class as well.

Comment: are you doing <context:component-scan> on this package correctly?

Comment: i use annotation @ComponentScan(basePackages  = "org.dstech.examplespring.controller")
and i found the error...i need to scan all packages and not only controller package. thanks for help me!!!